# React Syntax error: Unexpected token, expected ","

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ruby-on-rails, fetch-api

Following `https://blog.heroku.com/a-rock-solid-modern-web-stack` while adjusting to my own use case.

When I update my `app.js` file as follows:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  constructor () {
    super()
    this.state = {}
    this.getWords = this.getWords.bind(this)
    this.getWord = this.getWord.bind(this)
  }

  componentDidMount () {
    this.getWords()
  }

  fetch (endpoint) {
    return window.fetch(endpoint)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .catch(error => console.log(error))
  }

  getWords () {
    this.fetch('/api/words')
      .then(words => {
        if (words.length) {
          this.setState({words: words})
          this.getWord(words[0].id)
        } else {
          this.setState({words: []})
        }
      })
  }

  getWord (id) {
    this.fetch(`/api/words/${id}`)
      .then(word => this.setState({word: word}))
  }

  render () {
    let {words, word} = this.state
    return words
    ? {words && words.length
      ? {Object.keys(words).map((key) => {
          return <a href={word && word.id === words[key].id} onClick={() => this.getWord(words[key].id)}>
                  {words[key].term}
                </a>
        })}
      : <p>No word found.</p>
    }
    : <p>Loading...</p>
  }
}

export default App;
```

I get the following error:

```
./src/App.js
Syntax error: Unexpected token, expected "," (42:14)

  40 |     let {words, word} = this.state
  41 |     return words
> 42 |     ? {words && words.length
     |              ^
  43 |       ? {Object.keys(words).map((key) => {
  44 |           return <a href={word && word.id === words[key].id} onClick={() => this.getWord(words[key].id)}>
  45 |                   {words[key].term}
```

Despite a bit less structure in the layout of the page, the logic seems to be the same to me.

What I am missing?

**UPDATE**: I have edited the code as follows:

```
  render () {
    let {words, word} = this.state
    return words
    ? (words && words.length)
      ? (Object.keys(words).map((key) => {
          return <a href={word && word.id === words[key].id} onClick={() => this.getWord(words[key].id)}>
                  (words[key].term)
                </a>
        })
      : return
        <p>No words found.</p>
    }
    : <p>Loading...</p>
  }
```

and now I am getting the following error:

```
./src/App.js
Syntax error: Unexpected token (48:9)

  46 |                 </a>
  47 |         })
> 48 |       : return
     |         ^
  49 |         <p>No words found.</p>
  50 |     }
  51 |     : <p>Loading...</p>
```

I am obviously missing something, as I cannot figure out what the problem is: any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try replacing your `? {...}` with `? (...)`.

Comment: @FMCorz Actually I think he just needs to remove the curley brace on line 42. Either way, the code in this section is hard to read so, I suggest making it easier on the eyes, it will make it easier to maintain as well.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like there is an extra curly bracket, and the logic seems a bit off. Try this:

```
    return (words && words.length)
    ? Object.keys(words).map((key) => {
        return <a href={word && word.id === words[key].id} onClick={() => this.getWord(words[key].id)}>
              {words[key].term}
            </a>
        })
    : <p>No word found.</p>
```